# How would I solve for A, B and C?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, fractions

[image]

I have managed to write the equation in the non-simplified form but my attempts to simplify it lead me to a fraction that is not in the required form.

Any help?

Comment: What have your attempts gotten you?

Comment: yes, since this is manifestly homework, at least some work should be shown

Comment: I am going to try and write here the fraction I got. (((3sqrtx)-(3sqrtx+h))/h)              I hope that is clear. I do not know how to write fractions here. This fraction was not in the correct form.

Comment: Rationalise the numerator,then try eliminating h

Answer (score 0):

${f(x+h)-f(x) \over h} = 3 { \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h} \over h} = 3 { \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h} \over h} {\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h} \over \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h}}$.
Now simplify.